# Intra-class Correlation Coefficient (ICC) for a single subject

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I need to calculate a score that reflects the level of disagreement/ambiguity between raters for a music clip.

The experimental set-up is that 10 respondents listen to a clip with a one-dimensional slider in front of them scaled between a min and a max value; they move the slider based on how the clip makes them feel and the slider's position is recorded at a rate of 2Hz, i.e. it takes a real-valued reading every 0.5s.

End result of this is 10 dynamic annotation signals per clip; i.e. if the clip was 10s long, we have an array of (10x20) values, each row corresponding to an entry. Clips are of varying lengths.

ICC was just what I turned to with very limited stats knowledge and Googling, but I've struggled to get meaningful results. Taking the mean of each rater's responses for a clip and formulating the problem as ICC1 (from Shrout and Fleiss https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18839484) means that it's undefined for a single clip due to divide by zero errors.

Another possible formulation was treating each timestep as a single subject and calculating ICC2, however this gave me numerous negative values.

I'm certainly not wedded to ICC; I just need a statistic that relays information about voter disagreement for each example within my dataset. The metric is to be used as part of a corrective function for training a machine learning model. This may be a standard problem with an easy solution but it is not my area of expertise; if anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unlikely to help anyone but for future reference, Kendall's W is suitable in this situation.

Comment: Do you want to have disagreement over time, overall disagreement, or disagreement at each time point?

Comment: Overall disagreement - sorry should have clarified that.

Comment: Though what would be a suitable measure for individual time steps as well?